# Composer: zlib_decode data error

Tags: php, composer-php

I am facing a problem in my Composer installation. A few days back, it was working fine but now, it gives the following error:

> Failed to decode response: zlib_decode(): data error
>
> Retrying with degraded mode, check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#degraded-mode for more info

The degraded mode doesn't work too. I have searched around the web. Add `http-secure` config, tried upgrading, tried using composer.phar manually, tried adding repositories property to config but nothing worked.

I am using Windows. `composer --version` gives:

> Composer version 1.0-dev (e8abc90b923250527a2d68712b663f0f41790594)
> 2016-03-09 11:44:27

[image: Not working composer]

Comment: check what `composer diag` says

Comment: @Peh Everything's `OK` :O

Comment: Did you also add the `secure-http` flag instead of `http-secure`?

Comment: And did you scan through [14 similar issues](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+zlib_decode+)?

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes I had scanned the other 14 issues. I guess doing `secure-http` did it. Plus I used `-vvv` flag to keep an eye on what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

I have been facing a similar problem when I was trying to install a package in Laravel.
Simply add below lines in composer.json and everything will work like a charm. It helped me hope it helps!

```
"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packagist.org"
        },
        { "packagist": false }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ESSET antivirus you might need to disable HTTP-scanner, Refer to composer documentation for more instruction
[how to disable HTTP-scanner](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#degraded-mode)